# 9 patch not working correctly what i did wrong?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I did many search and I am really confused.

Here is my 9 patch file, result on device and XML of my button. Please tell me what's wrong about it

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnFlightInfo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btntest1"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:text="Flights"
    android:textColor="@color/white" 
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

[nine patch file](http://s30.postimg.org/vnphi36kd/btntest1.png)
[image]

[result on android device](http://s23.postimg.org/nt0e93ktn/Screenshot_2015_04_26_11_57_46.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Make sure the image is saved as .9.png

Comment: Thank you man. you are a life saver!!! what a mistake. my baaaad.

Comment: It happens bro. ;) Nothing to be ashamed of, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this [file](http://s30.postimg.org/vnphi36kd/btntest1.png) is the picture in your project, you should save your picture with btntest1.9.png to specify at android this is a nine patch.

Comment: Thank you. I know that but i don't know how i missed that. I'll mark it as answer as soon as possible.